# DynamoDB global user table transaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm re-exploring the world of AWS and I know global tables don't support transactions so I am not sure how to solve this problem. I have a USER global table that stores information about my user with the USERNAME being the partition key. One edge case I am worried if USER A creates a new account with username = "BOB" and USER B comes a second later and creates a new account with the same "BOB" before the first account was written to the table and replica tables, would USER B override this account or what would exactly occur?

This is just one example, I am trying to apply the same concept to my other tables.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_HowItWorks.html#V2globaltables_HowItWorks.conflict-resolution):

> If applications update the same item in different Regions **at about the same time**, conflicts can arise. To help ensure eventual consistency, DynamoDB global tables use a **last writer wins** reconciliation between concurrent updates, in which DynamoDB makes a **best effort to determine the last writer**. With this conflict resolution mechanism, **all the replicas will agree on the latest update** and converge toward a state in which they all have identical data.

Based on the above, DynamoDB will make **best effort** to determine the last writer, in that case USER B. Then all replicas will agree on that and use USER B's data as the final result.

The key phrase is **best effort**. So its not guaranteed that it will always happen that way.

Comment: To expand on this answer, if OP wanted to prevent a user from overriding another user's acoount.... you can't. BUT the likelihood of this scenario from happening is very low, so you'll be probably be okay if you let it slide. :)